# Alert if no files written > 7 days

Tags: powershell

Each week we have a backup file replicate over to a folder on our file server. I'm looking for a way to notify me if a file has not been written to that folder in over 7 days.

I found this script online (I apologize to the author for not being able to credit), and I feel like it put's me on the right track. What I'm really looking for though is some kind of output that will tell me if a file hasn't been written at all. I don't need confirmation if the backup is successful.

```
$lastWrite = (get-item C:\ExampleDirectory).LastWriteTime
$timespan  = new-timespan -days 7
if (((get-date) - $lastWrite) -gt $timespan) {
    # older
} else {
    # newer
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Want you'll want to do is grab all files in the directory, sort by `LastWriteTime` and then compare that of the newest file to 7 days ago:

```
$LastWriteTime = (Get-ChildItem C:\ExampleDirectory |Sort LastWriteTime)[-1].LastWriteTime
if($LastWriteTime -gt [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-7))
{
    # File newer than 7 days is present
}
else
{
    # Something is wrong, time to alert!
}
```

For the alerting part, check out [`Send-MailMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage) or [`Write-EventLog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/write-eventlog)

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. I have a few questions though. Whenever I enter in a write-eventlog statement in where it says # Something is wrong," nothing happens. I tried modifying the script so that the first 2 lines are a single line, then the second line starts out with If ($LastWriteTime -eq 'False'){Write-EventLog -LogName but when doing so it wrote the log every time regardless of if a file was out of date or not. Am I supposed to be replacing the Green text with the Write Event Log statements?

Comment: The `#` means "comment, ignore everything on this line after the #" - put your `Write-EventLog` statement on the next line (or replace the comment completely)

Comment: Please disregard that last comment. The script above worked like a charm. The problem was with syntax in my write-eventlog statement. Thank you so much.